# LMDB Seek (move the cursor) without read

Tags: c++, lmdb

I would like to know whether it is possible to move the cursor forward for, say, n positions without retrieving data at the same time (i.e. lowering i/o load).

I am aware of `mdb_cursor_get` but it seems to retrieve the data from disk at each call in combination with `MDB_NEXT`.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a NULL pointer for the data argument and it will skip the retrieval.
In practice, for small records that all fit on a leaf page, there will be no performance difference since this is mmap'd and zero-copy.